# Join tables with multiple rows in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

This is what my **products** table looks like,

```
id | name | price
-----------------
1  | soap | 20.00
```

This is what my **product_images** table looks like,

```
id | product_id | image_url
---------------------------
1  |     1      |   http://someurl
2  |     1      |   http://someurl
3  |     1      |   http://someurl
```

As you can see each `product` has many `images`. I want to get this data but the `product_images` should be an array like this,

**What I'm expecting,**

```
   [
    {"id": 1,"name": "soap","price": 20.00, 
     [
      {"id": 1,"image_url": "http://someurl"},
      {"id": 2,"image_url": "http://someurl"},
      {"id": 3,"image_url": "http://someurl"}
     ]
    }
   ]
```

But instead, I'm getting one record at one time with duplicates of the product. This is the way I tried that,

```
 return DB::table('products')
   ->join('product_images', 'product_images.product_id', 'products.id')
   ->get();
```

Comment: The Best practice for working with Database is  in Laravel is to using Elequent . 
migrate your code to Elequents .

Comment: I haven't worked with joins using Eloquent, Really appreciate it if you would explain my question scenario using eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use laravel [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

First, create two models `Product` and `ProductImage` using php artisan command .Then add relationship one to many to product images

```
 php artisan make:model Product
```

and

```
php artisan make:model ProductImage
```

the above command will create two models in following path

```
app/Models/
```

so in model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
    public function productImages(){
        
        return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class);
    }
}
```

So your query will look like this

```
 $products=\App\Models\Product::with('productImages')->get();
```

Comment: This returns me error 500, Where is the reference to product_id and id?

Comment: @MishenThakshana check what exactly the 500 error states in log file. if you have followed laravel convention then no need specify reference

Comment: exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\RelationNotFoundException

Comment: @MishenThakshana have you created ProductImage model class ?

Comment: Thanks really appreciate your help. But I have a doubt regarding adding one more table like that. Imagine having a stocks table , how to return both stocks and images now?

Comment: return Product::with('productImages')->with('productStocks')->get();

Comment: add one more relation to product and then in with(['stock','productImages'])  .just google it you will get so many resources before asking help in stackverflow.so you will learn yourself

Comment: I got it thanks, I did like above and it worked